# Erro ao carregar o arquivo CSS, não consigo achar o diretório

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, css3, express.js

Estou fazendo um app simples, mas estou me confundindo toda no acesso as pastas. Eu quero chamar o arquivo about.css dentro do arquivo layout.njk. Os diretórios que já tentei nenhum funcionaram.

A estrutura das minhas pastas são essas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

arquivo layout.njk

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

arquivo about.njk

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu arquivo server.js:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou querendo acessar a rota localhost.

Comment: Qual erro te da? Você já tentou colocar o path absoluto do arquivo CSS?

Comment: Não dá erro, só não carrega. Já tentei o caminho absoluto.

Comment: Parece que nesse caso seu arquivo CSS ta sendo carregado de uma outra pasta

Comment: @Ruth Maria quando postar o **código** Evite por em imagens isso dificulta para quem vai analisar sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigada por avisar, @Edu Mendonça. Eu não sabia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu arquivo `layout.njk` você está voltando um nível para importar o `about.css` sendo que a pasta `styles` existe apenas na pasta public.

Como você está servindo a pasta `public` como estática, você pode importar o css assim

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/about.css" >
```

Certifique que a sua pasta `public` está sendo exposta, no arquivo `server.js` altere a linha existente para essa

```
server.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`))
```

Comment: Oi, Filipe. Eu tentei essa solução e ainda não funcionou :'(

Comment: Editei a resposta, pode conferir por favor?

Comment: FUNCIONOUUUUUUUUU... Muito obrigada ^.^

Comment: Disponha, fico feliz em saber que funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Seu arquivo `layout.nkj` esta em `site/views` quando você volta um diretorio, consequentemente você vai trabalhar dentro do diretorio `site`, então digamos que o `..` seria o diretorio `site` e para chegar no `about.css` teriamos que passar o restante do caminho `site/public/styles/about.css` e assim vamos substituir o `site` pelo `..` ficando assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles/about.css" >
```

Comment: Oi, Thiago. Eu tentei essa solução e ainda não funcionou :'(